# Guice - Injection of Listeners

Tags: guice

I have a singleton service created by Google Guice. The service has register/deregister listeners methods. Some of the service methods send a notification to the registered listeners. 
Is there a way in Guice to de/register some of listeners at bootstrap? I also want to have the possibility to add listeners during runtime.

Thanks,
Soccertrash

Comment: Would you mind posting a code sample to help understand the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a Provider (or Provides Method)

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public YourService provideService(ListenerA a, ListernerB b) {
YourService service = new YourService();
service.register(a);
service.register(b);
return service;
}
```

You can than later add Listerner c by Hand.